# A question about mixture of 全称 and 简称

Tags: word-choice

For example, there is a college known as 华中科技大学 based in Wuhan, Hubei Province，and another college 中国科技大学 in Hefei, Anhui Province. So far there is not anything unusual until it turns out that the latter is a shortened from the full 中国科学技术大学, yet in the case of 华中科技大学, it is not 华中科学技术大学 in full.

Another example is the name of government agencies, 公安部 uses the short form(whose full should be 公共安全部  because its official translation in English is Ministry of Public Security), but 国家安全部 does not use 国安部 instead.

So we see the short and full forms are used on the same level. Why is so?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, in most area, a uniform nomenclature is not necessary. Because both 公安 and 科技 are all widely known terms and are used much more than their original words. For example in English, gym is Short for gymnasium and more used (also like bike&bicycle, fridge&refrigerator). Organizations can use "gym" or "gymnasium" as a part of their name.

On the other hand, 公安 is a very common word before the 公安部 was founded, so they can use 公安 as a name, whereas 国安 is not a widely known term before the 国家安全部 was founded. So 国安部 at the founding time will be a confusing name for public.

Comment: Yes, it's like "State Security" and "National Security"

Comment: As far as I know, 公安 is a name of  a place if  it doesn't mean public security. For example, 公安派是明神宗万历（1573-1620）年间以袁宏道及其兄袁宗道、弟袁中道三人为代表的文学流派，因三人是湖北公安人而得名。Obviously, they could not possibly be  police officers （公安人）but native people of Gong'an County.

Comment: @NanningYouth Yes you are right. But what you said is just a coincidence. The 公安 in the 公安局 has nothing to do with the 公安county. The "public safety" meaning of 公安 started using in the early twentieth century. The Kuomintang government at that time had a 公安局. And there is no evidence that the choice of this name has anything to do with 公安县 or 公安派(literary style). Existing information generally tends to be the name given by the Kuomintang government under the influence of the Japanese troops stationed in China at that time. And this word in Japan is imported from France.

Comment: About the irregular nomaclature, there are more  cases like 上海市上海县，长沙市长沙县，吉林省吉林市，南昌市南昌县，公安县公安局。Words like 投资公安  may be misleading when they appear on the home page of gov website.

Comment: @NanningYouth Although Chinese is a high-context culture language and has much more homophones than other popular languages, native speakers have a lot of ways to avoid misleading. For example, the 公安县 is not popular and rare to be mentioned. So in most context, 公安 just means public security. For your example, if a page said "投资公安", it should be the 公安县 because public security in China doesn't need to 投资。On the other hand, i believe a professional reporter will say "湖北省公安县" when mentioning 公安 county not just 公安.